# error TS2322: Type 'List | undefined' is not assignable to type 'any[] (Iterable<any> & any[]) | (any[] & Iterable<any>) | null | undefined'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am following along to a youtube tutorial for angular, I see that it is bad practice to apply `any` to a variable so I changed it to be assigned to my `List` and `Task` models and it seems to have thrown a big fit

**Error Message**

```
Error: src/app/pages/task-view/task-view.component.ts:27:60 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call. 
      Overload 1 of 5, '(observer?: NextObserver<Object> | ErrorObserver<Object> | CompletionObserver<Object> | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
        Argument of type '(tasks: Task[]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NextObserver<Object> | ErrorObserver<Object> | CompletionObserver<Object> | undefined'.
          Property 'complete' is missing in type '(tasks: Task[]) => void' but required in type 'CompletionObserver<Object>'.
      Overload 2 of 5, '(next?: ((value: Object) => void) | undefined, error?: ((error: any) => void) | undefined, complete?: (() => void) | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
        Argument of type '(tasks: Task[]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Object) => void'.
          Types of parameters 'tasks' and 'value' are incompatible.
            The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
              Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'Task[]': length, pop, push, concat, 
and 26 more.
    
    27         this.taskService.getTasks(params.listId).subscribe((tasks: Task[]) => {
                                                                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    
      node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts:64:5
        64     complete: () => void;
               ~~~~~~~~
        'complete' is declared here.
    src/app/pages/task-view/task-view.component.ts:34:42 - error TS2769: No overload matches this call.        
      Overload 1 of 5, '(observer?: NextObserver<Object> | ErrorObserver<Object> | CompletionObserver<Object> | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
        Argument of type '(lists: List[]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type 'NextObserver<Object> | ErrorObserver<Object> | CompletionObserver<Object> | undefined'.
          Property 'complete' is missing in type '(lists: List[]) => void' but required in type 'CompletionObserver<Object>'.
      Overload 2 of 5, '(next?: ((value: Object) => void) | undefined, error?: ((error: any) => void) | undefined, complete?: (() => void) | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
        Argument of type '(lists: List[]) => void' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: Object) => void'.
          Types of parameters 'lists' and 'value' are incompatible.
            The 'Object' type is assignable to very few other types. Did you mean to use the 'any' type instead?
              Type 'Object' is missing the following properties from type 'List[]': length, pop, push, concat, 
and 26 more.
    
    34     this.taskService.getList().subscribe((lists: List[]) => {
                                                ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    
      node_modules/rxjs/internal/types.d.ts:64:5
        64     complete: () => void;
        'complete' is declared here.
```

**task-view.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRoute, Params } from '@angular/router';
import { TaskService } from 'src/app/task.service';
import { MatDialog } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import { Task } from 'src/app/models/task.model';
import { List } from 'src/app/models/list.model';




@Component({
  selector: 'app-task-view',
  templateUrl: './task-view.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./task-view.component.scss']
})
export class TaskViewComponent implements OnInit {

  lists?: List[];
  tasks?: Task[];

  constructor(private taskService: TaskService, private route: ActivatedRoute, private dialog: MatDialog) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.route.params.subscribe(
      (params: Params) => {
        //console.log(params);
        this.taskService.getTasks(params.listId).subscribe((tasks:Task[]) => {
          this.tasks = tasks;
        })
      }

    )

    this.taskService.getList().subscribe((lists:List[]) => {
      console.log(lists);
      this.lists = lists;
    })
  }

  onTaskClick(task: Task) {
    // We want to set the task to completed
    this.taskService.complete(task).subscribe(() => {
      console.log("Completed successfully");
    })
  }


  


}
```

**task-view.component.html**

```
<div class="centered-content">
    <div class="task-manager-container"> <!---->

        <div class="sidebar has-background-white">
            <h1 class="title has-text-primary">
                Lists
            </h1>

            <div class="list-menu">
                <a *ngFor = "let list of lists" class="list-menu-item has-text-primary" [routerLink]= "['/lists', list._id]" routerLinkActive= "is-active">
                    <p>{{list.title}}</p>
                </a>
            </div>

            

            <button mat-raised-button class="button is-medium is-primary has-text-light " routerLink = "/new-list">
                <mat-icon>add</mat-icon> New List
            </button>
        </div>

        <div class="task-list-container has-background-light">
            <h1 class="title has-text-primary">
                Tasks
            </h1>

            <!-- Task Elements -->
            <div *ngFor = "let task of tasks" class="task-list has-text-primary" (click) = onTaskClick(task)>
                <p> {{ task.title }} </p>
            </div>

            <button class="circle-add-button button is is-primary" routerLink = "./new-task">
                <mat-icon>add</mat-icon>
            </button>
        </div> 


    </div>
</div>
```

**task.service.ts**

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Task } from './models/task.model';
import { WebRequestService } from './web-request.service';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class TaskService {

  constructor(private webReqService: WebRequestService) { // this line is injecting the web-request service we created

   }

  createList(title: string) {
    // We want to send a web request to create a List
    return this.webReqService.post('lists', { title }); // this is returning a observable
  }

  getList(){
    return this.webReqService.get('lists'); 
  }
  
  getTasks(listId: string) {
    return this.webReqService.get(`lists/${listId}/tasks`);
  }
  
  createTask(title: string, listId: string) {
    // We want to send a web request to create a Task
    return this.webReqService.post(`lists/${listId}/tasks`,{ title }); // this is returning a observable
  }

  complete(task: Task){
    return this.webReqService.patch(`lists/${task._listId}/tasks/${task._id}`,{
      completed: true // maybe could be set to !completed?
    } )
  }
  

}
```

Comment: What does taskService look like..?

Comment: @MikeOne Check edit

Comment: Add explicit return types to the functions in the service. Your component needs to know that the functions in the service return what it expects. If you don't, *any* is assumed.

Comment: @R.Richards How would I go about doing that?

Comment: Something like this ```getTasks(listId: string): Observable<Task[]> {
    return this.webReqService.get<Task[]>(`lists/${listId}/tasks`);
  }```

Comment: That seemed to fix the issue